# Output is not getting written in nohup.out while starting the server from jenkins

Tags: linux, shell-script, nohup, jenkins

I have written a shell script to start a server which is mentioned below and this script is executed from jenkins via ssh.

nohup ./startWeblogic.sh &

The server is getting started alright but the output is not getting written in nohup. But the command works fine if it is run in putty. Why is it so? Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `set -ex` to get to know whats exactly happening, that might help.
Even try logging manually in the script itself.